# Converting a nested list into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have look up several solutions, but all of them involve using numpy and complex codes, i am still a beginner and have not learned about this yet . Can anyone please offer an easier solution (i.e using a loop) on how to convert a nested list into a dictionary. The example question and the code i have tried is below:

Convert the original list into a dictionary such that the keys for each sublist are: “power1”,
#“power2”, “power3”, “power4”, “power5” in that order.

I have tried doing the following code, however it only prints the last inner list:

```
{'powers1': [1, 32], 'powers2': [1, 32], 'powers3': [1, 32], 'powers4': [1, 32], 'powers5': [1, 32]}
```

This is the code that i have tried:

```
powers = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], [1, 8, 27, 64], [1, 16, 81], [1, 32]] #this is the original list

powers_dictionary = {}
list_powers=["powers1","powers2","powers3","powers4","powers5"]

for ele in powers: 
  for i in list_powers:
    powers_dictionary.update({i:ele})

print(powers_dictionary)
```

Comment: `dict(zip(list_powers, powers))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version, using explicite loops:

```
powers_dictionary = {}

list_powers=["powers1","powers2","powers3","powers4","powers5"]
powers = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], [1, 8, 27, 64], [1, 16, 81], [1, 32]] #this is the original list

for idx, power in enumerate(list_powers):
    powers_dictionary[power] = []
    for p in powers[idx]:
        powers_dictionary[power].append(p)

print(powers_dictionary)
```

Prints:

```
{'powers1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'powers2': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], 'powers3': [1, 8, 27, 64], 'powers4': [1, 16, 81], 'powers5': [1, 32]}
```

---

Note: Using `dict()` with `zip()` is more efficient and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keys = ["powers1","powers2","powers3","powers4","powers5"]
values = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], [1, 8, 27, 64], [1, 16, 81], [1, 32]]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i want to ask is there any way that we can use a for loop to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to use a `for` loop?  `dict` and `zip` are much more efficient.